# Render Category View based on Products search

Tags: magento2, ajax, search

I'm trying to build a Live search. I have a Block Class that returns the necessary the products that i want to show.

Now the Result page or the Category Page has a Controller that outputs the grid as far as i understand it.

My question is if i can use those and how to output my own grid with those products.

A big thanks for who is willing to help me out here!

**Edit**

With the help of Ajax and giving it the input value and getting it in my template with the $_GET function and giving it to my block class i'm able to get the products that match the filter.

Still need a way how to output the products in a grid layout.

**Edit 2**

I outputted it as a raw controller html which is good for loading time. Still searching how to get XML logics within my raw controller.